# Why machine learning algorithms focus on speed and not accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I study ML and I see that most of the time the focus of the algorithms is run time and not accuracy. Reducing features, taking sample from the data set, using approximation and so on.

Im not sure why its the focus since once I trained my model I dont need to train it anymore if my accuracy is high enough and for that if it will take me 1 hours or 10 days to train my model it does not really matter because I do it only 1 time and my goal is to predict as better as I can my outcomes (minimum loss).

If I train a model to differ between cats and dogs I want it to be the most accurate it can be and not the fasted since once I trained this model I dont need to train any more models. 
I can understand why models that depends on fasting changing data need this focus of speed but for general training models I dont understand why the focus is on speed.

Comment: You need to be specific, as the question is too general, you saw something, where and what exactly? From my experience I would say exactly the opposite, that we focus too much on accurate models and not enough in fast ones.

Comment: I think speed has always played a big role in algorithmic in general. It's a good way to compare effective working algorithms. Because if you allow yourself an infinite amount of time (and here of data) it's easy to achieve 100% accuracy.

Comment: I saw in many example using max drop functions and this kind of functions, reducing image sizes and so on. I dont understand why we want to lose info of our data for the trade off of speed.

Comment: Yes here the idea is to speed up the training, in the same way some people like to use float coded on 16 bits instead of 32, and so on. In fact since you are using in most cases a grid search, you "expect" your model to be robust engough to cope for lack of information or poor informations. And if one cannot their are much more that are trained in parallel. But indeed it seems very counterintuitive. (and maybe it is)

Answer (score 1):

Speed is relative term. Accuracy is also relative depending on the difficulty of the task. Currently the goal is to achieve human-like performance for application at reasonable costs because this will replace human labor and cut costs.

From what I have seen in reading papers, people usually focus on accuracy first to produce something that works. Then do ablation studies - studies where pieces of the models are removed or modified - to achieve the same performance in less time or memory requirements.

The field is very experimentally validated. There really isn't much of a theory that states why CNN work so well other than that it can model any function given non-linear activations functions. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) There have been some recent efforts to explain why it works well. One I recall is MobileNetV2: Inverted Residuals and Linear Bottlenecks. The explaination of **embedding data into a low dimensional space without losing information** might be worth reading.